# Adding scss to html when they are on the same level

Tags: html, css, sass

I have `<h1 class='title home'> My Title </h1>`, and to add styles I can do

```
      .title {
        font-size: 1.95em;       
      }

      .title .home {
        color: black;
      }
```

This works but I want to know if there a way to put the `home` inside `title`? Something like this:

```
    .title {
        font-size: 1.95em;

        .home {
          color: black;
        }      
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for the [parent selector](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/style-rules/parent-selector)

```
.title {
   font-size: 1.95em;

   &.home {
          color: black;
       }      
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is the one of the main benefits to using SASS/SCSS. You can use the parent selector/reference `&`:

```
.title {
        font-size: 1.95em;

        &.home {
          color: black;
        }      
      }
```

This compiles to:

```
.title {
  font-size: 1.95em;
}
.title.home {
  color: black;
}
```

Documentation:
https://sass-lang.com/documentation/style-rules/parent-selector